# How to get the StorageFile given its starting name without querying the entire StorageFiles in a folder? Winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

In WinRT is there a way by which you can directly get the `StorageFile` given its starting name.

- Ex: File name : "ABCDEFGH" and I have to get the file given I know it
  starts with "ABCD".
- Please note I would not like to do a `StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()`
  and checking each file as this takes a lot of time.

What are my options if any?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the QueryOptions class to search for a file in a storage folder

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR207995